# Как вывести в шаблоне кластера сумму всех значений у объектов внутри этого кластера?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Дано: с сервера приходит коллекция с геоданными и некоторым числом (допустим sum). Мне нужно вывести все эти точки на карте + кластеризация. Когда точки объеденены в кластер на кластере должно отображаться не количество точек внутри кластера (как по дефолту), а сумма всех значений sum тех точек которые находятся внутри этого кластера (вух надеюсь понятно написал).

Научился кастомизировать шаблон кластера, научился вытаскивать данные и суммировать у каждого конкретного кластера, но вот подружить это дело никак не получается.

Набросал небольшой пример того как я это делаю и снабдил комментами чтобы было понятно мою логику.

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    // определяем объект кары
  const myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.90, 36.86],
    zoom: 10
  });

    // определяем шаблон вывода суммы в иконке кластера
  const MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    "<span style='color: #000;'>{{ options.orderSum }}</span>"
  );

    // определяем ObjectManager
  const objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    clusterIconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout
  });

  // Симуляция ajax запроса
  setTimeout(function() {
    // данные которые пришли с сервера
    data = [{
        lat: "55.9062267",
        long: "36.8601454",
        sum: 500
      },
      {
        lat: "55.907",
        long: "36.8601454",
        sum: 1000
      },
      {
        lat: "55.9065",
        long: "36.8601454",
        sum: 1500
      },
    ];

        // формируем коллекцию объектов карты
    const features = data.map(element => {
      return {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [element.lat, element.long]
        },
        data: {
          order: element.sum
        }
      };
    });

    const collection = {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features
    };

        // добаляем коллекцию объектов в манагер
    objectManager.add(collection);

        // добавляем манагер на карту для вывода объектов
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

        // проходимся по всем видимым кластерам, производим суммирование data.order во всех объектах и записываем полученное значение в options кластера
    objectManager.clusters.each(cluster => {
      let orderSum = 0;
      cluster.features.forEach(pin => {
        orderSum += parseFloat(pin.data.order);
      });

      objectManager.clusters.setClusterOptions(cluster.id, {
        orderSum
      });
    });

        // тоже самое что и выше только при изменении кластера
    objectManager.clusters.events.add("add", event => {
      let orderSum = 0;
      event.get("child").features.forEach(pin => {
        orderSum += parseFloat(pin.data.order);
      });

      objectManager.clusters.setClusterOptions(
        event.get("child").id, {
          orderSum
        }
      );
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Потыкать в песочнице: https://jsfiddle.net/2w9f58us/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохранил данные суммы в корень объекта кластера и все заработало.

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    // определяем объект кары
  const myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.90, 36.86],
    zoom: 10
  });

    // определяем шаблон вывода суммы в иконке кластера
  const MyIconContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    "<span style='color: #000;'>{{ orderSum }}</span>"
  );

    // определяем ObjectManager
  const objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    clusterIconContentLayout: MyIconContentLayout
  });

  // Симуляция ajax запроса
  setTimeout(function() {
    // данные которые пришли с сервера
    data = [{
        lat: "55.9062267",
        long: "36.8601454",
        sum: 500
      },
      {
        lat: "55.907",
        long: "36.8601454",
        sum: 1000
      },
      {
        lat: "55.9065",
        long: "36.8601454",
        sum: 1500
      },
    ];

        // формируем коллекцию объектов карты
    const features = data.map(element => {
      return {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [element.lat, element.long]
        },
        data: {
          order: element.sum
        }
      };
    });

    const collection = {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features
    };

        // добаляем коллекцию объектов в манагер
    objectManager.add(collection);

        // добавляем манагер на карту для вывода объектов
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

        // проходимся по всем видимым кластерам, производим суммирование data.order во всех объектах и записываем полученное значение в options кластера
    objectManager.clusters.each(cluster => {
      let orderSum = 0;
      cluster.features.forEach(pin => {
        orderSum += parseFloat(pin.data.order);
      });

      cluster.orderSum = orderSum;
    });

        // тоже самое что и выше только при изменении кластера
    objectManager.clusters.events.add("add", event => {
      let orderSum = 0;
      event.get("child").features.forEach(pin => {
        orderSum += parseFloat(pin.data.order);
      });

      objectManager.clusters.setClusterOptions(
        event.get("child").id, {
          orderSum
        }
      );
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/vUdav/z3n9h6Lb/7/